# Core Data difference between parent/child and to-one/to-many inverse relationships

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data

I've looked all over SO, youtube, and the Apple docs and am having real trouble understanding the distinction--if any--between parent/child and to-one/to-many inverse relationships in Core Data. Nothing I've found appears to address the subject directly and explicitly.

I need to know this because I want to load a table view with data from one entity, called ListActivity, grouped into sections defined by another entity called ListCategory, as shown here. Also not real confident of my naming convention:

[image]

Can someone please clearly explain the difference--and when to use each case--or point me to something that can?

Thanks!

**Edit for clarification:**

For comparison, here is a screenshot of my entities with ListCategory specified via the menu in the Data Model Inspector as the Parent Entity for ListActivity:

[image]

Comment: Stick with the top model for a simple CD model. The bottom one essentially works the same, but is more for an "isA" relationship. It will also allow you to inherit parent attributes so you only need "name" in parent, and subclass will inherit name. Just like subclassing objects.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'm starting to get the idea that everyone who knows about this stuff found out by trial and error. Doesn't seem to be well documented, unless I've missed something big. :)

Comment: This will more than help you out http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G36_91H4CKE

Answer (score -1):

Relationship is used go down in an object graph (i.e activities in a category) while an inverse relationship is used to go up in an object graph (i.e category to which an activity belong to).

While naming convention looks fine. better use "activities" instead of "listActivities" and "category" instead of "toCategory".

Generate classes for them and you'll better know how these will work out.

Comment: I appreciate the response, but it doesn't really address the question: What is a Parent/Child relationship, and what distinguishes it from an inverse relationship?